# Incorrect positioning of a DIV

Tags: css

On my webpage over at http://www.replyonline.co.uk/avaya/16312_UC_ms/costs/index.html you will see a twitter div named #twitter.

As you can see, it looks out of position and needs to be after the 4 #about divs to the left of it, but also needs to line up with the others. It looks pushed down currently.

I've fiddled with the CSS but haven't had any luck.

Here's the CSS for the about boxes and the twitter box:

```
#about{
width: 260px;
min-height: 140px;
float: left;
margin: 0 35px 10px 0;
background: url(../images/about_grad.jpg) bottom right;
display: block;
}

#twitter{
float: right;
width: 260px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
height: 290px;
overflow: auto;
font-size: 11px;
background: #ececec;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a wrapper `div` (no styling) around the `a` linked items and removed the `float:right` attribute of the twitter box - that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `float: right` from `#twitter`.